# Google Sheet - Single Evaluation / Separate Instance for Various Users /Single Comparison Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

- I have created a monthly performance evaluation table + dashboard in google sheets.
- Now a separate instance of this evaluation is going to used by around 30+ users.
- At the end of this, I will get 30+ dashboards and tables.
- From these 30+ evaluations, I aim to create 1 main comparison table preferably in a separate google sheet.

What is the best way to go about this?

Right now, I can think of this simple way.

- Create 30+ copies of the table+dashboard google sheet.
- Provide link of each sheet to each user.
- Save them all in a folder on google drive.
- Create a new spreadsheet and bring in the output data from 30+ sheets for comparison in this new sheet.

This seems too much work and I feel I might be missing something obvious in this regard due to lack of knowledge. An add-on? or an app script? I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Script is one option. A non-script option would be to use a combination of `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE`. So for multiple sheets, you could do something like this (below) in A2:

`={IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL1","SheetName!Range");IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL2","SheetName!Range");IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL3","SheetName!Range")}`

I've found it's easier to pull data into one sheet with `IMPORTRANGE`, then use `QUERY` or `ARRAYFORMULA` to sort and put the data into a sheet the any viewer sees.

You could do it all at once by doing `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL1","SheetName!Range");IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL2","SheetName!Range");IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL3","SheetName!Range")},"Select * where Col1<>'' order by Col2 asc",0)`

You could use the shareable link from the master sheet and get that to everyone.